# How do I improve execution time in my script in python?

Tags: python, time, geospatial

I'm trying to remove values from files containing 3 dimensional arrays corresponding with the dimensions corresponding to `[time][long][lat]`.

I have separate files for each years worth of data.  I have a list of observed data points `T_obs` for a duration of time `start_time_index` to `end_time_index` that I want to compare to the mean value over that time period in the file data.

The data sets contained in the files are sufficiently large that my code is running very slowly and I want to optimize my execution time. The code I have currently is below. Are there any ways I could significantly save time?

```
T_obs = [1.5, 3.6, 4.5]
start_time_index = [20, 300, 10]
end_time_index = [40, 328, 200]
long_obs = [45, 54, 180]
lat_obs = [34, 65, 32]
LE = np.zeros(len(T_obs))
t = 1984

for filename in os.listdir("C:\\Directory"):
    if filename.endswith(".nc"):
        print(filename)
        fh = Dataset("C:\\Directory %s"
                     % filename, 'r').variables['matrix']
        for i in range(0, len(long_obs)):
            if year[i] == t and start_time_index[i] > 0:
                LE_t = []
                for x in range(int(start_time_index[i]), int(end_time_index[i])):
                    LE_t = np.append(LE_t,float(fh[x][long_obs[i]+180][lat_obs[i]*-1+90])/10)
                LE[i] = np.mean(LE_t)
        t += 1
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Some questions and remarks: 1) Consider using [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to build the path to you file, it's more robus than your solution. 2) Where is the variable `year` coming from? 3) What is the `Dataset` Class doing? 4) Have you tried using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for this? - It's usually the right tool for this kind of job and faster in most cases. 5) You can remove the last three lines, they have no effect.

Comment: consider turning this into a multi thread process? You are processing each file individually, so you could run 50+ of those simultaneously. look at the threading module

Comment: If your code is otherwise working without any errors, a better place to ask could be [codereview.se]. Stack Overflow specializes in not-working code.

Comment: You could define your ``fh`` variable before your loops. You may want to look into python generators and possibly some multi-threading. If you profile your code, you can find non-performant areas and write them in c++ instead. https://docs.python.org/3.4/extending/extending.html

Comment: You can replace your loops with a nested list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to do this kind of work many times (with different values), or just once?

If the former, you can try to put your files data in a database (such as [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/), which is simple to setup) and create indexes on the start and end time. This would make your reads mighty faster, as you would not need to do a full table scan (which is pretty much what you are doing by reading the whole file).

If you are doing it just once, then I just suggest you wait it out. There is no trivial way to make I/O (which is your bottleneck) less expensive and it seems like to make your checks / compare the data, you actually need to go through the whole dataset.